# Is there a way to get the "remember me" checkbox work on Azure Mobile Service authentication for WinRT apps?

Tags: authentication, azure, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to add Azure Mobile Service authentications to my WinRT app. I got everything working and I can sign in with all the 4 social media accounts(Facebook, Twitter, Google and Microsoft Account). But when I close the app and restart it, I have to write my user name and password even if I check the Remember Me button on either one of the options. Let say I logged in with my Facebook account, what I want to achive is, when I restart the app and click Login with Facebook, it shouldn't ask my username and password but automatically authenticate me. The remember me button seems to not working. Is there a way to achive this?
Thank you for the answers.

Edit: I'm using C#/XAML for my my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following blog post covers caching the user's identity. http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Setting_the_auth_token_in_the_Mobile_Services_client_and_caching_the_user_rsquo_s_identity_Day_10_.aspx

Comment: I saw this post a few hours after I posted this question. Now I'm using something very similar to this one. Hope it can help someone else. Thank you for posting.

Answer (score 1):

According to this page: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-users-dotnet/

> Note 
>   ... This method is easy to configure and supports multiple providers. However, this method also requires users to log-in every time your app starts. To instead use Live Connect to provide a single sign-on experience in your Windows Store app, see the topic [Single sign-on for Windows Store apps by using Live Connect.](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/single-sign-on-windows-8-dotnet/)

Comment: I don't know how I missed this paragraph but still, you can't use anything other that Microsoft Account with this option.